# http-bind url is not loading on installing ejabberd 17.09

Tags: ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd 17.09 deb package in Ubuntu 16.04 
But the http-bind url (like http://x.x.x.x:5280/http-bind) is not loading in order to confirm the running status of newly installed ejabberd on starting the same.
Error Message: This site can’t be reached. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Also, I'm unable to register admin.
Error Message: Error conflict

Could you please help me to ascertain the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you check if the port is bound and/or in use on your host machine? you can do that by: ss -planeut | grep 5280

Comment: This is the output received:   ss -planeut | grep 5280
tcp    LISTEN     0      5        :::5280                 :::*                   uid:999 ino:2825522 sk:25 v6only:0 <->  Please HELP